# Does the Data Export module support exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views

I am looking to use the *Data Export* module to export data to CSV files. However, I need the users to be able to filter the data first with exposed filters and then download the filtered results.

From what I can see, the module seems to be an all or nothing module.

Does anyone know if it is configurable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you create a Data Export view, there is an option to attach it to another view. You can choose to attach it to another page in the same view and all the filters used would be affected by the export. A new icon would be shown at the bottom of the view to download the exported data.

In the following screenshot, I attached it to a view page.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: You need to have the same filters exposed with the same settings on the data export view as your desired display view and attach the data export view to your same desired display. This worked for me.

Comment: They do work together, though I have found that filter settings must be the **EXACT** same as the parent display that the export is attached to (including whether filters are exposed, labels etc). I have found that even if I make a slight change to one it needs to be updated on the other to continue working.

Answer (score 3):

Hope [this tutorial](http://drupalthread.blogspot.com/2014/04/data-export-and-exposed-filter-for-date.html)  might help you!

Here's a summary:

1. Create a view for the content type you're interested in (i.e : article)
2. Add the data export display and a page display.
3. Add all needed fields in your data export display.
4. Add the date popup calendar in “Filter criteria” and tick on the exposed filter option.
5. In the Data export display just below the path  option you'll find  "attach" where you need to attach your page display in it.
6. Select "*Parent sort*" in the data export display settings.
7. Navigate to the path you've given in the page display , and you'll see the date filtering field which contains a date popup and an orange button called 'csv' or 'xls' embedded below your filtered contents.