# Data export with exposed filters

Tags: views

I want to use the Views data export module and some exposed filter to export my data as csv. I followed the steps and comments mentioned in this link:
[Does the Data Export module support exposed filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58551/does-the-data-export-module-support-exposed-filters)

and I put the same exposed filters and same fields in the export display as well as in the page display. They have now the exact same configuration and I chose the BASIC exposed form style for both and I have added a reinitialization button for both of them as well and everything works good.

When I go to the page's path  and apply a filter, and press download as CSV, the CSV file contains the filtered data (which is good). Now , if  I then press reinitialize on the page display, all results reappear (which is what I want), but if I click download as csv, the data that is exported is the previously  filtered one not all the results, this is happening despite having all the results appearing on the page display!!

I tried to remove the Remember previous selection from both of the displays but it didn't change anything. Seems that exposed filters of the export display are working just like those on the page however there must be a problem regarding the reinitialization button. If clicked on the page, it is not applied on the export.

Comment: Try turning on "Use AJAX" in your view settings.

Comment: Is the CSV file named the same the second time? Maybe try a time-related variation in the name so it doesn't fetch the same file name.

Comment: Thank you both ! will try that !
@prkos can you please give me more details on how to do that ?

Comment: IIRC there should be Settings for the export where you enter tokens for the file name, so you can make it variable depending on the data set or time. I haven't tried it but I'd check that. I remember having the exposed filters working with CSV export flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @prkos i tried it but didn't work. i put the name of my csv file as %exposed.csv . whenever I click on reinialize i get the same file name which means that the exposed filters are not initialized.  I have a reinitialize button in the settings of my export view and another one in the page view and I checked remember last selection of the exposed filter in both displays and the exposed filters are select lists in both displays . Could that be the problem>?

Comment: It's possible, try without that option.